# Is domain attribute of a cookie sent back to a server?

Tags: http, cookies, browser, security

If evil.example.com sets a cookie with a domain attribute set to .example.com, a browser will include this cookie in requests to foo.example.com.

[The Tangled Web](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/tangled/) notes that for foo.example.com such cookie is largely indistinguishable from cookies set by foo.example.com. But according to [the RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), the domain attribute of a cookie should be sent to the server, which would make it possible for foo.example.com to distinguish and reject a cookie that was set by evil.example.com.

What is the state of current browsers implementations? Is domain sent back with cookies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RFC 2109 and RFC 2965 were historical attempts to standardise the handling of cookies. Unfortunately they bore no resemblance to what browsers actually do, and should be completely ignored.

Real-world behaviour was primarily defined by the original Netscape cookie_spec, but this was highly deficient as a specification, which has resulting in a range of browser differences, around -

- what date formats are accepted;
- how cookies with the same name are handled when more than one match;
- how non-ASCII characters work (or don't work);
- quoting/escapes;
- how domain matching is done.

RFC 6265 is an attempt to clean up this mess and definitively codify what browsers should aim to do. It doesn't say browsers should send `domain` or `path`, because no browser in history has ever done that.

Because you can't detect that a cookie comes from a parent `domain`(*), you have to take care with your hostnames to avoid overlapping domains if you want to keep your cookies separate - in particular for IE, where even if you don't set `domain`, a cookie set on `example.com` will always inherit into `foo.example.com`.

So: don't use a 'no-www' hostname for your site if you think you might ever want a subdomain with separate cookies in the future (that shouldn't be able to read sensitive cookies from its parent); and if you really need a completely separate cookie context, to prevent `evil.example.com` injecting cookie values into other `example.com` sites, then you have no choice but to use completely separate domain names.

An alternative that might be effective against some attack models would be to sign every cookie value you produce, for example using an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

*: there is kind of a way. Try *deleting* the cookie with the same `domain` and `path` settings as the cookie you want. If the cookie disappears when you do so, then it must have had those `domain` and `path` settings, so the original cookie was OK. If there is still a cookie there, it comes from somewhere else and you can ignore it. This is inconvenient, impractical to do without JavaScript, and not watertight because in principle the attacker could be deleting their injected cookies at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was thinking that if all sites served as *.example.com are handled by the same server, the server could drop HTTP responses that try to set cookies with domain set to '.example.com' and thus enforce isolation between sites. But I realized that cookies can be also set from JavaScript, which breaks the isolation. Are you aware on any other way in which a server could enforce isolation of *.example.com sites (other than serving them from completely separate domain names)?

Answer (score 1):

The current standard for cookies is [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265). This version has simplified the `Cookie:` header. The browser just sends cookie `name=value` pairs, not attributes like the domain. See section 4.2 of the RFC for the specification of this header. Also, see section 8.6, **Weak Integrity**, where it discusses the fact that foo.example.com can set a cookie for .example.com, and bar.example.com won't be able to tell that it's not a cookie it set itself.

Comment: Do you know if current browsers follow this RFC and do not sent domain with cookies?

Comment: No, I don't. Why don't you fire up a packet capture program and see? However, even if they do send the data, I'm not sure how you would use it. The CGI specification doesn't include passing this information to the application. E.g. PHP's `$_COOKIE` variable only contains the names and values, not attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe Zalewski's book and his https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main over any RFCs. Browsers' implementations of a number of HTTP features are notoriously messy and non-standard.